# How to handle login sessions and cookies for mobile device

Tags: php, iphone, yii

We are developing an iPhone application which has server side coding in the YII PHP framework. 
Is there any way to handle login sessions and cookies for mobile devices, or are there any settings which YII supports for handling cookies and sessions for devices?

I think that Yii provides some solution for this, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [NSUserDefault](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to store the session.

You can work around it to store the session and cookies.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"SessionKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"Cookie"]) {
     //session and cookie alive
     logInSession= [defaults objectForKey:@"SessionKey"];
     logInCookie= [defaults objectForKey:@"Cookie"];
}else{
     //you might want to present a login view then generate session key etc
     logInSession = @"new session";
     logInCookie = @"new cookie";
     [defaults setObject:logInSession forKey:@"SessionKey"];
     [defaults setObject:logInCookie forKey:@"Cookie"];
     [defaults synchronize];
}


-(void)logOutAndClear
{
  //do logout here, clear you defaults
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"SessionKey"];
}
```

this is a very simple and not the best way to accomplish what you want. check [NSHTTPCookieStorage](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/Reference/Reference.html), that might help

EDIT: code above is just to express the idea, not tested.

Comment: Hi janusfidel, could you please explore it ?

Comment: Hi janusfidel, i'll go through your reply, Thanks